# How to change a Struct named Error to implement Error protocol in swift

Tags: swift

I have a struct named 'Error' and I want to implement 'Error' protocol in struct.
I did

```
public struct Error: Codable, Error {
}
```

But I get error

```
 error: inheritance from non-protocol type 'Error'
public struct Error: Codable, Error {
```

Is there a way to add a namespace to specify the Error protocol in swift?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For native Swift types, you can prepend `Swift.` to the type to tell the compiler to use the native type instead of your own.

In your case, you would do this:

```
public struct Error: Codable, Swift.Error {
    // ...
}
```